# same problem, camera rpi not works ENOSPC

Tags: camera

i have raspberry pi Type B and i am trying to attach camera into it,

all i have done is upgrading dist and firmware

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rpi-update

all firmware is updated

now according to what i saw commonly in google i have to execute raspistill

raspistill -v

and this is what i've got

```
raspistill Camera App v1.3.8

Width 2592, Height 1944, quality 85, filename (null)
Time delay 5000, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

ENOSPC error always showing ,

this is my /etc/modules

```
w1-therm
w1-gpio pullup=2
i2c-dev
i2c-bcm2708
spi-bcm2708
snd-bcm2835
#lirc_dev
#lirc_rpi gpio_out_pin=7
```

my /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf

```
# blacklist spi and i2c by default (many users don't need them)

#blacklist spi-bcm2708
#blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

uname -r

3.12.25+

i cant figure what is wrong with this error, someone know how to solve it?
please help me to solve it.

Comment: did you run the sudo raspi-config and enable the camera support? (plus reboot)

Comment: i have . still not working

Comment: can you find someone else with a Pi and try it on theirs or borrow another camera? I have two Pi cameras and both a model A & B and never had a problem getting them working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be issue [#435](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/435) that the camera doesn't play nice with Dallas 1-wire stuff. Elucidation's post (8th Jan) in that ticket is apparently one to look at (seen a couple of reports stating that particular config worked) - your configuration looks very similar, but for the fact that the "blacklist i2c-bcm2708" line is commented out. You might want to try uncommenting that?

Failing that, try commenting out the 1-wire (w1-*) modules in `/etc/modules` just to see if that makes a difference. If it does, at least you'll know it is the 1-wire/I2C conflict causing the issue.

Comment: yep it did good for my Pi, but when all complete , pi stuck at capturing camera 0, and it never give me an image, thanks btw